# WPF desktop application connectionString - RSA key container decryption issues

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption, connection-string, app-config

I have a standalone .net/wpf app that uses a connection string to talk to a mysql db. 
The connectionString is in app config. I then used the aspnet_regiis tool to get an RSA encrypted version. It works beautifully on my machine when I fetch the connection string through my c# code.

However, when I distribute my app to another machine, it fails to decrypt. I assume / understand this is because the RSA key container on the target machine doesnt know how to decrpyt.

Now, how do I deploy a suitable key to the target machine? Is there a procedure I can read about and try out? I do not wish to perform a machine specific action. If I can deploy something like a public key on the target machine that can help decrypt my connection key that would be of massive help. Is this achievable ?

Thanks

Comment: In which database will the distributed application talk to? It seems like you are trying to solve a very specific problem, and encounter an even bigger one if you overcome this.

Comment: The mysql db is in a remote cloud. Have I answered your question ?